# Wildcard pattern overriding subtype constraint on polymorphic variant

Tags: types, ocaml, type-inference, subtyping, polymorphic-variants

Given these types

```ml
type a = [ `A ]
type b = [ a | `B  | `C ]
```

and this function

```ml
let pp: [< b] -> string =
  function | `A -> "A"
           | `B -> "B"
           | `C -> "C"
```

applying a value of type `a` works without issue, as expected:

```ml
let a: a = `A
let _ = pp a
```

However, if the function is modified to include a wildcard pattern

```ml
let pp: [< b] -> string =
  function | `A -> "A"
           | `B -> "B"
           | _ -> "?"
```

even though everything else remains the same, it now yields the following error (on `let _ = pp a`):

> This expression has type b -> string but an expression was expected of type a -> 'a Type b = [ `A | `B ] is not compatible with type a = [ `A ] The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `B

Questions:

1. Why is it no longer able to accept a subtype? I understand the wildcard means it now CAN accept a supertype, but that shouldn't mean it MUST.
2. Is there some way of getting around this, to avoid having to enumerate a million or so variants that aren't relevant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying question is why the type of

```
let pp= function
| `A -> "A"
| `B -> "B"
| _ -> "?"
```

is infered as `` [> `A| `B] -> string `` and not as `` [< `A| `B | ... ] -> string `` (where `...` stands for any constructor). The answer is that is a design choice and a question of compromise between false positive and false negative : https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~garrigue/papers/matching.pdf .

More precisely, the second type was deemed too weak since it was too easy to lose the information that `` `A `` and `` `B `` were present in `pp`. For instance, consider the following code where `` `b `` is a spelling mistake and should have been `` `B ``:

```
let restrict (`A | `b) = ()
let dual x = restrict x, pp x
```

Currently, this code fails with

> Error: This expression has type [< `A | `b] but an expression was expected
>   of type [> `A | `B ]
>   The first variant type does not allow tag(s) `B

At this point, if `` `b `` was a spelling mistake, it becomes possible to catch the mistake here. If `pp` had been typed `` [< `A|`B |..] ``, the type of dual would have been restricted to `` [`A] -> unit * string `` silently, with no chance of catching this mistake. Moreover, with the current typing, if `` `b `` was not a spelling mistake, it is perfectly possible to make `dual` valid by adding some coercions

```
let dual x = restrict x, pp (x:[`A]:>[>`A]);;
(* or *)
let dual x = restrict x, (pp:>[`A] -> _) x
```

making it very explicit that `restrict` and `pp` works on different sets of polymorphic variants.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the second version of `pp` is `` [< b > `A `B ] -> string ``. In other words, `` `A `` and `` `B `` must appear in the type. I guess it seems reasonable that if you want to compare a value against `` `B `` then `` `B `` should appear in the type of the value.

You can write `pp (a :> b)`.

Comment: In itself it might seem reasonable, but wouldn't it be just as reasonable for the function that enumerates all the variants? +1 for `:>` though, I didn't realize it could be used for poly-variants too!